# when add @Transactional cannot initialize dao bean

Tags: spring, transactional, cglib

In a dao of a legacy project I add a new method, then I wrote a unit test to test the new method

```
FooDAO dao = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"applicationContext.xml"}).getBean("FooDAO");  
@Test
public void test_getUnenabledArtisanIdsByReverseTime(){
    String reverseTimeStr = "2016-02-18 19:00";
    List<String> artisanIds = new ArrayList<>();
    artisanIds.add("1");
    artisanIds.add("2");
    dao.getUnenabledArtisanIdsByReverseTime(artisanIds, reverseTimeStr);
}
```

it failed, throw below exception

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

Then I add below configuration in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

and add `@Transactional` above the new method

```
@Transactional
public List<String> getUnenabledArtisanIdsByReverseTime(List<String> artisanIds, String reverseTimeStr)
```

Then execute unit test again, failed too, but it's another exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FooDAO' defined in file [/home/zhuguowei/workspace/myapp/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/artisan/repository/FooDAO.class]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: 
Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class com.foo.artisan.repository.FooDAO]: 
Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.ClassCastException-->java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
```

very strange, the dao is public and not final class

```
@Component
public class FooDAO extends BaseDaoHiber4Impl<Foo>

public BaseDaoHiber4Impl() {
    this.entryClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

So what's the reason of this problem and how could to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cglib proxy works by creating a new class, extending the target class, and overriding each method.

When the proxy is created, your constructor fails :

```
(ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()
```

getClass() is now the proxy, and getGenericSuperclass() is the current class (`FooDAO`), which is not a `ParameterizedType`

Possible workaround :

1. It looks like you are trying to reimplement spring-data : give it a try instead :-)
2. Don't use cglib proxies : Define an interface for your DAO, make FooDAO implement it, and inject this interface instead of your class.
3. Handle the case where FooDAO is extended : iterate through all getGenericSuperclass() to find the first `ParameterizedType` instance

Comment: Thanks! but could you have some better manner solve this problem

Comment: Thanks! but you know this is a legacy project

Comment: HI does exist some manner could let the dao method not must be in a transaction, e.g.  `<prop key="hibernate.must.within.transaction">false</prop>`